# iOS SpriteKit pause game if orientation is portrait

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I added `view.paused = YES;` to my `applicationWillResignActive` on appdelegate.

But how do I call this pause when the orientation is portrait? I want to pause my game both on button click and orientation is on portrait and resume on button touch.

Also added `view.paused = NO;` to my `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLayout {
    [super viewDidLayout];
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)) {
        view.paused = YES;    
    }
}
```

`viewDidLayout` is a method called any time the view has to layout all its subviews.  This happens on the initial load of the view, as well as any time the orientation changes.  It can also be called in other instances (I'm not entirely certain what these all are), like when you set the view as needing a layout.

`UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait()` is a macro that returns `YES` or `NO` based on whether or not the orientation is portrait or not.  There is a similar macro called `UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape()`.